Uniqueness condition for points that minimize the distance between two sets
Suppose that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is a open bounded smooth domain and $(x_n) \subset \Omega$ is a sequence such that $d(x_n,\partial\Omega) \to 0$, as $n \to +\infty$, where $d(x_n,\partial\Omega) = \inf\{|x_n - y|\hspace{0.1cm}; \hspace{0.1cm} y \in \partial\Omega\}$.
I saw during my studies that these conditions are sufficient to guarantee the uniqueness (for $n$ big enough) of a point $y_n \in \partial\Omega$ such that
$$|x_n - y_n| = d(x_n,\partial\Omega).$$
What I know is: For each $n$, the sets ${x_n}$ and $\partial\Omega$ are compacts. Then, there exists some $z_n \in \partial\Omega$ such that $|x_n - z_n| = d(x_n,\partial\Omega)$. But I don't know how to prove uniqueness using the above hypothesis.
By a smooth domain I mean the following: For each $x_0 \in \partial\Omega$ there exists a ball $B=B_r(x_0) \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and a bijective function $\psi: B \to A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ such that
(i) $\psi(B\cap\Omega) \subset \mathbb{R}_+^N$;
(ii)$\psi(B\cap\partial\Omega) \subset \partial\mathbb{R}_+^N $;
(iii) $\psi \in C^\infty(B)$ and $\psi^{-1} \in C^\infty(A)$;
where $\mathbb{R}_+^N = \{(x_1,\cdots, x_N) \in \mathbb{R}^N\ \hspace{0.1cm} ; \hspace{0.1cm} x_N >0\}.$
It can be shown that this definition is equivalent to saying that each
point on $\partial\Omega$ has a neighborhood whose intersection with ∂Ω is the graph of a function of $N − 1$ of the coordinates $x_1$, $\cdots$ , $x_N$, with this function being of class $C^\infty$.

Yes, this is even true for smooth submanifolds of other dimensions. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood

Here is a sketch of an elementary proof.
First, the idea: smooth hypersurfaces look like hyperplanes if you zoom in far enough. Since $d(x_n, \partial\Omega) \to 0$, by taking $n$ large, we can zoom in until the picture looks very similar to a hyperplane $P$ and a point $x_n$ not belonging to $P$. We know there is a unique point in $P$ that is closest to $x_n$: it's the point $x_0$ such that the vector $x_n - x_0$ is perpendicular to $P$. (This is a well-known fact that can be shown by linear algebra or calculus.)
To make this rigorous, you need to account for the fact that $\partial \Omega$ isn't quite a hyperplane. If $d(x_n,\partial\Omega) = \varepsilon$, then we can pick coordinates so that $x_n = (0,\ldots,0,\varepsilon)$ and $\partial\Omega$ is locally the graph of a smooth function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1})$ with $f(0) = 0$. Using Taylor's Theorem, you can trap $\partial\Omega$ under a paraboloid $x_N = M(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{N-1}^2)$ for some $M>0$, and then one shows by a calculation that for $\varepsilon$ small enough, this paraboloid lies below the sphere of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x_n$, and intersects the sphere only at the origin. This means that there is only one point in  $\partial\Omega$ at a distance $\leq \varepsilon$ from $x_n$.
